# Support different versions of the same dependency

Tags: java, maven

The framework I am developing on has to support 2 versions of the same library. Those versions contain breaking changes, but we don't need those parts! What we would like now is to guarantee that those methods are never called on accident.

e.g.

- guava 18.0 `HostAndPort.from("127.0.0.1").getHostText()`
- guava 23.0 `HostAndPort.from("127.0.0.1").getHost()`

**Is there any way to ensure that such breaking methods are never called for future commits without manually checking each commit?**

---

What we have done so far is, that we provide the library in version 23.0 with some sub-module (foo.a) and added the 18.0 version as provided in the "higher level" module (b).

module foo.a

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

module b

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This way integration tests should identify any clashes, if we manage to have 100% line coverage. BUT unittests would not, see "provided" quote maven:

> This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

meaning unit tests would still use version 18.0

Comment: Your have to create two separate integration test modules. One has one version of the lib the other the other version of the dependency. And run you integration tests...